# hide password in string

Tags: c#, security, string, passwords, obfuscation

I am making a custom ftp client that logs onto a single ftp site and goes to a specific folder to avoid users' putting files in the wrong place.

I'm not super concerned about it, but the password is just a string to initiate the new ftp object.

```
FtpClient ftp = new FtpClient("www.markonsolutions.com", "user", "password");
```

What is the best way to keep this password from prying eyes?

Comment: Use arabic chars. They're unreadable to 99% of people.

Comment: @David Rutten: Care to explain why? Arabic appears to be the world's sixth most spoken language. (http://www2.ignatius.edu/faculty/turner/languages.htm)

Comment: Consider a different approach. Assume that bad people will get the password, so first, set the account up so that it only has write access and only to the specific directory you're using. Second, is it feasable/reasonable/appropriate to prompt the user for the password?

Comment: @Bob Kaufman We are hosted through godaddy so its an 1 key to the castle thing. 

@David + @joshJordan I don't agree but just because somethings 6th doesn't mean many people read it(either way I wont be using that trick)

Comment: Heh... had the same issue with GoDaddy for a file upload. FWIW, my approach was to create a web-based client that uploaded the file via HTTP to a R/W UserFiles directory. The filename was a function of the username and the timestamp. I should stress that this is security through obscurity and that the content of the file wasn't anything worth stealing.

Comment: obfuscation is never a good solution to security.

Answer (score 10):

FTP supports only plain text authentication - if you want to hide the password from attackers you have to use  [FTPS (FTP over SSL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS).

**UPDATE**

Don't care about hiding and obfuscating the password in your source code as a first step - your application will have to decrypt it and send it over the wire in plain text. Everyone can just start [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or any other packet sniffer and get the password back in plain text. **First make sure that you don't send the password in plain text over a network, then start thinking about obfuscating it in your code.**

**UPDATE**

Obfuscating the password in your code yields no security at all while you are sending it in plain text, but you can do so. Just encrypting the string adds one level of indirection. Without obfuscation I have to finde the password in your application and that's a matter of minutes with [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), with obfuscation I have to find the key, the encrypted password, and the encryption method. This will probably still take only minutes.

Using an obfuscator to prevent me from decompiling you application (into readable code) might stop me for a few hours until I find the relevant call into a system library function (but I wouldn't try, but only read the password from the wire ;).

So I suggest not to try to hard to obfuscate the password - the average user is probably unable to find a plain text password in a executable and people willing to find the password cannot be stopped by obfuscation. In this case the only way would be not to include the password in your application in the first place.

Comment: +1 - I thought we were only going to see answers here that dealt with obscuring the password in the .NET assembly.

Comment: this is correct i am not worried about sniffing right now but i will be thinking about this later

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this](http://www.foss.kharkov.ua/g1/projects/eazfuscator/dotnet/Default.aspx) to protect your plain text string from **reflector** like programs.

Comment: Has anyone else heard of this tool?  I have an inherent distrust of running software I have never heard of (especially when it's hosted in Ukraine).  This isn't listed on download.com.  I would love to get some reliable references because that looks like a nice tool.

Answer (score 1):

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-decrypt-string-in-c) about how to encrypt and decrypt a string, in this case your password.

You should also consider [obfuscating](http://blogs.msdn.com/clrsecurity/archive/2005/05/26/422440.aspx) your code to make it difficult for people with appropriate tools to get the password by debugging your code.

Comment: It is much easier to start a network sniffer like WireShark (http://www.wireshark.org/) and read the password directly from the wire after the application decrypted it.

Comment: Agree, I was looking at the question narrowly (guess I needed that 2nd cup of coffee after all).  We use sftp for exactly that reason.

Answer (score 0):

Make your passwords and connection URLs configuration parameters, in a protected file.  I uses INI files, and they are placed in a directory that is protected by the web server such that a browser can't open nor see the file/directory.

Comment: You can call a web service from an exe, which has the advantages of Jay's solution, without the need for a web application.